# Reusing search pattern in ex mode

Tags: ex-mode

Sometimes I want to try a pattern with `/` before doing `:%s/ …`; can I reuse it without having to type it all over? (or use the mouse.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, just leave the pattern in the substitution empty:

```
:%s//replacement/
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@garyjohn's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4778/46), you can use `<c-r>/` to insert the search register into a command if you want to edit it or leaving out the search pattern isn't sufficient.

```
:%s/<c-r>//replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution

```
:exe '%s/' . @/ . '/replacement/g'
```